# Feed string using slack webhook

Tags: python, slack

So basically, I have a set of data (domain name, severity score) that is in string format as post, and I am trying to get it to post in slack and It keeps throwing errors out and I don't know why. I appreciate the help.

I have tried changing the JSON portion a bit to see if it was that as well as changing what is being sent to the function in general, and nothing helps.

def slackHook(post):
    webhook_url = #Ommited

```
slack_content = {"channel": "@brian", "user": "Awesom-O", "attachment": [{
 "type": "section",
 "text": {
  "text": "Random message before domains",
  "type": "mrkdwn",
     },
 "fields": [
  {
   "type": "mrkdwn",
   "text": "Domain             Severity Score"
  },
  {
   "type": "plain_text",
   "text": post
  }
 ]
}]}
string_payload = json.dumps(slack_content)
r = requests.post(webhook_url, data=string_payload)
if r.status_code != 200:
    raise ValueError('Request to slack.com returned an error %s, the response is:\n%s' % (r.status_code, r.text))


domains = db_query()
domains = str(domains)
slackHook(domains)
```

Happy Path: I would just like to take my string and post it to my slack channel using the fields that I've given for context.

The current error:

```
raise ValueError('Request to slack.com returned an error %s, the response is:\n%s' % (r.status_code, r.text))

ValueError: Request to slack.com returned an error 400, the response is:
no_text
```

Comment: At the moment there is a severe outage of all Slack services. I would wait until the outage is over before continuing with your testing. Check the status here: https://status.slack.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you where mixing the syntax for attachments and blocks which are different concepts. attachments are outdated and should no longer be used.

Just replace `"attachment"` with `"blocks"` like so:

```
slack_content = {"channel": "@brian", "user": "Awesom-O", "blocks": [{
```